# Default Tokyo DLL compiler switches disallows old component unit references

Tags: forms, delphi, dll, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Compiling Win 32 DLL that contains a a Tokyo 10.2.3 form, I get compiler errors on 3rd party components used in the form that reference units with "namespaces" like Forms vs VCL.Forms.   Changing the references allows the component units to compile, but MANY components have to be changed.

Example:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] OvcCmd.pas(44): F2613 Unit 'Forms' not found.

Compiling the Tokyo form as a separate project EXE does NOT generate the compiler errors.

For Delphi Gurus:
Is there a compiler switch configuration for compiling and building a DLL that will tell Tokyo to use/ignore the older style unit declarations?

Comment: They are not ["namespaces"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi), they are ["unit scope names"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names). Two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Unit aliases to the DLL Project Options resolved the compiler errors:

[image]

Comment: This is not the correct solution. You are dealing with ["unit scope names"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names), so make sure that `VCL` is included in the project's list of known unit scope names.

Comment: You are correct!  Many thanks.  Adding Vcl to the Projects Unit scope names is a more elegant solution, than adding Unit aliases.   Interesting that a Win32 VCL Forms project includes Vcl in the Unit Scope Names by default, but a Win32 DLL project does not....

Comment: Probably because DLLs are not expected to use the VCL framework by default.